# How to Refresh entire app after rest call / how to to refresh app after an event

Tags: reactjs

How to refresh or reload application after any event occurred or after a rest api call. I am using react with webpack. After event occurred or after rest api call, I need to refresh for displaying response in the app . I want my application has to reload by-default once any event occurred in the app. How to implement this?

My folder structure is given bellow
App --> 1) Add
    --> 2) List --> Table --> 1)Update 2) Delete

once item is deleted/update that should effect to table and list
   once item added that also

Comment: I think you  might be confuse about how react works, are you sure you need to reload the app and not just to repaint your view with the latest data ?

Comment: You should manage state to handle the list...then save the api response to state, when the state will update it will update your display. Read more: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react

Comment: @sebastienbarbier i need  view my latest data. While refreshing the app am getting latest data. i don't want to do that.

Comment: What you need to look for is some documentation about react lifecycle and how it render, refresh html. You should use states as describe by barak_dev.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use following java script method to reload the react app

```
window.location.reload();
```

As you mentioned it is for development purpose so it will work , But when page is reload project state values are reset , so it cause the issue in your project if you handle proper way 
 of Authentication , state values then it fine